# How to make only eventSources droppable into FullCalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

i use FullCalendar and i call my Event with eventSources and ajax like this :

```
eventSources: 
        [
            {
                url: 'ajax.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                   obj: 'Event'
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                }

            },          
        ],
```

the Return JSON Code look like this :

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Event One","town":"London","start":"2011-05-10","url":"","title":"Event One","className":"Event_class","description":"Hier some description","color":"#D42993","draggable":"false"},{another Events}]
```

So far it's all good, then i tried to make just those event Droppable(not the Calendar), so that i can drag an external object into it(for example a "Manager").

I change the eventSources in this way but it dont work :

```
eventSources: 
        [
            {
                url: 'ajax.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                   obj: 'Event'
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                },
                textColor: 'black',
                                    disableDragging: true,
                cache: true,
                                    dropAccept: '.Personal',
                droppable : true,
                                    eventDrop: function(e, ui){ alert("drop")}
            },          
        ],
```

Can Someone Help me on this One? Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful giving us the api for the plugin,

Comment: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/ I think eventDrop expects more parameters to be added instead of just `e,ui`

Comment: the api can u find http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! just use eventRender like this :

```
eventSources: 
        [
            {
                url: 'ajax.php',
                type: 'POST',
                ...
                                    dropAccept: '.myClass',//class of my external elts
                droppable : true
            },          
        ],
    droppable: false, //make the rest of our Calendar not droppable  
eventRender: 
        function(event, element) {//Our events -> from eventSources
                            element.droppable({//make only my events droppable
                                accept: '.myClass',//my external elts
                                activeClass: 'droppable-active',
                                hoverClass: 'droppable-hover',
                                drop: function(e, ui){ }//Actions
                             })               
        }
```